# My Laptop Feels Like It's Overheating. (Acer)

Tags: laptop, cooling, temperature

I use Real Temp for a temperature check a lot, the normal temperature is: 50-55ᵒc. The highest it went is 73-77ᵒc, the lowest it went is: 48-49ᵒc. Are these normal temperatures for an Acer laptop?

I normally use Google Chrome and Roblox Player Launcher, the normal tab usage on Chrome is 2-4. When I feel like It's overheating, I turn it off and wait for it to cool down before I use it again. When I don't feel like turning my laptop off, I keep the 2 side ends on the keyboard on the side of my knees and let the fan cool off the laptop. When I use 1-2 tabs, It starts to get a bit hot, when I use 4, it cools down.

Is my normal temperature okay for this type of laptop? (Acer). The size is unknown though.

Comment: Those temperatures are normal. I've had laptop's that run much hotter than that. Just be sure you're letting the laptop get enough ventilation.